# how to print only a certain part of data file mathching our pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

i want to print certain blocks of data from a file using python . Basically it should work as a parser and only output the blocks mathcing my criteria .
My file contains logs of a call center . I want the part starting with "####" and ending on  `"</soap:Body>>"` but it should also contain a certain number in it known as msisdn in my file as : `"<msisdn>any number</msisdn>"`

Also the file is kind of big . So when i do the readlines() , i cannot use the regex using for i,data in enumerate(line) 
                here the data is split and i cant search the whole chunk that i require .

the part of the file is here:

```
####<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Debug> <MessagingBridgeRuntimeVerbose> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1465022150722> <BEA-000000> <Bridge NPGBridge doTrigger(): state = 4 stopped = false> 
####<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Error> <ALSB Logging> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1465022150886> <BEA-000000> < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, CreateVASReportingStage, REQUEST] *** CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS V-3.0 ***: <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <VASProxyType xmlns="http://xmlns.aircel.com/AircelTransformation/ProxyService/OrderProxy/1.0/CreateVASSubscriptionConsumerSchema">
    <TransactionId>DATA030620160431128801011429ADD</TransactionId>
    <msisdn>8801011429</msisdn>
    <productCode>DATA</productCode>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <IMSI>405801124044563</IMSI>
    <SubsType>PrePaid</SubsType>
  </VASProxyType>
</soap:Body>> 
####<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Error> <ALSB Logging> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1465022150889> <BEA-000000> < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, Authentication, REQUEST] ***REQUEST FOR VAS V-3.0 ****: <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <VASProxyType xmlns="http://xmlns.aircel.com/AircelTransformation/ProxyService/OrderProxy/1.0/CreateVASSubscriptionConsumerSchema">
    <TransactionId>DATA030620160431128801011429ADD</TransactionId>
```

the output should be :

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1465022150886>  < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, CreateVASReportingStage, REQUEST] *** CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS V-3.0 ***:

DATA030620160431128801011429ADD
    8801011429
    DATA
    ADD
    405801124044563
    PrePaid
  
>

kindly help!

Comment: Just use a XML parser; using regular expressions will just be a headache.

Comment: *"data is entered is wrong"* - what? *"kindly ignore it"* - no, you [edit] the question.

Comment: There is no part ending on "</soapenv:Body>>" in the data you provided. Please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments suggested: Your XML is not valid. It would be better to ensure valid XML and then use a parser like [etree][1] or [Beautiful Soup][2].

But if you want to use regex anyway, you could try:

```
import re

mytext = [
    '####<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Debug> <MessagingBridgeRuntimeVerbose> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: \'13\' for queue: \'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)\'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1465022150722> <BEA-000000> <Bridge NPGBridge doTrigger(): state = 4 stopped = false>',
    '####<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Error> <ALSB Logging> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: \'13\' for queue: \'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)\'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1465022150886> <BEA-000000> < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, CreateVASReportingStage, REQUEST] *** CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS V-3.0 ***: <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">',
    '<VASProxyType xmlns="http://xmlns.aircel.com/AircelTransformation/ProxyService/OrderProxy/1.0/CreateVASSubscriptionConsumerSchema">',
    '    <TransactionId>DATA030620160431128801011429ADD</TransactionId>',
    '    <msisdn>8801011429</msisdn>',
    '    <productCode>DATA</productCode>',
    '    <action>ADD</action>',
    '    <IMSI>405801124044563</IMSI>',
    '    <SubsType>PrePaid</SubsType>',
    '</VASProxyType>',
    '</soap:Body>',
    '<Jun 4, 2016 12:05:50 PM IST> <Error> <ALSB Logging> <ggneai29> <AircelESB_MS1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: \'13\' for queue: \'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)\'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1465022150889> <BEA-000000> < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, Authentication, REQUEST] ***REQUEST FOR VAS V-3.0 ****: <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">',
    '    <VASProxyType xmlns="http://xmlns.aircel.com/AircelTransformation/ProxyService/OrderProxy/1.0/CreateVASSubscriptionConsumerSchema">',
    '        <TransactionId>DATA030620160431128801011429ADD</TransactionId>',
]

searches = [
    {
       "if_in": "<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread:",
       "search": "<\[ACTIVE[^<>]+> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <\d+>",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, Create",
        "search": "< \[PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, Create[^\[\]]+\]",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS",
        "search": "CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS[^*]+",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "<TransactionId>",
        "search": "(?<=<TransactionId>)[^<>]+",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "<msisdn>",
        "search": "(?<=<msisdn>)[^<>]+",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "<action>",
        "search": "(?<=<action>)[^<>]+",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "<IMSI>",
        "search": "(?<=<IMSI>)[^<>]+",
    },
    {
        "if_in": "<SubsType>",
        "search": "(?<=<SubsType>)[^<>]+",
    },
]

result = ""
found_once = []

for item in mytext:
    for search in searches:
        if search['if_in'] in item and search['if_in'] not in found_once:
            f = re.findall(search['search'], item)
            if f:
                result += f[0] + " "
                found_once.append(search['if_in'])

print result
```

If you want to find anything else, add it to `searches`.

Result would be:

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1465022150722> < [PipelinePairNode1, PipelinePairNode1_request, CreateVASReportingStage, REQUEST] CreateVASWrapper Reprting Stage VAS V-3.0  DATA030620160431128801011429ADD 8801011429 ADD 405801124044563 PrePaid
```

Comment: i am not dealing with xml . these are the files downloaded . i am reading this file as text file . i open the file and then i want to display only the part which contains the required information . not the whole file

Comment: also i'm doing it all using python . i used readlines() to fetch the data of the file and now i'm stuck on how to display the required information

Comment: Yes, currently it is not well-formed XML, but it would be easier. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to handle such problems is to write some kind of "event-based" parser (like SAX xml parsers...): your parser reads the file line by line (you don't need to read the whole content in memory), scan the line according to your own rules (that's where you may want to use regexps, but sometimes plain string methods are just as efficient) and depending on the line content's emit a given "event" (that will be handled by a callback method) with the relevant data.

In your case you would have an event for lines starting an interesting block of data (lines starting with "####"), another one for lines containing xml data, and an event for the last line of the block (lines containing "") - something like this:

```
class Parser(object):

    def parse(self, logfile):
        self.in_block = False
        for line in logfile:
            if self.is_block_start(line):
                self.in_block = True
                self.handle_block_start(line)
            elif self.in_block:
                if self.is_data(line):
                    self.handle_data(line)
                elif self.is_block_end(line):
                    self.in_block = False
                    self.handle_block_end(line)
            else:
                continue

    def is_block_start(self):
        # your code here

    def is_data(self):
        # your code here

    def is_block_end(self):
        # your code here

    def handle_block_start(self, line):
        # your code here

    def handle_data(self, line):
        # your code here

    def handle_block_end(self, line):
        # your code here
```